C invert the bits of a 16 bit integer
This code won't simply invert the bits of the 16-bit integer as expected:
#include <stdint.h>
typedef uint16_t U16;

U16 myNum = 0xffff;
~myNum // 0xffff0000, not 0x0000

Because C will promote the 16-bit integer to a 32 bit integer before doing the inversion (see 1, 2).
What are my options for 16-bit bitwise inversion? I can think of:
~myNum & 0xffff
// or 
((U16)~myNum)

But they seem prone to mistakes/misunderstanding. Am I just out of luck if I want a neat 16-bit inversion?

Why can't you just do (uint16_t)~myNum?

I'm fairly new to C and want to check that casting is indeed the best way to bitwise-invert a 16-bit value, so that I can improve and learn about the language

Well, prone to mistakes/misunderstanding is the only way to do that then.

Just assign back to a uint16_t variable? Like U16 myNewNum = ~myNum;? And when you print the value, use the correct format macro constant PRIu16 (or PRIx16 if you want to print in hexadecimal).

How about xor? myNum ^ 0xffff

Anyway, that code doesn't represent what you really do: you are not just ~myNum like that, as a void statement (or else, how would you know what is its value). You are doing something with it. int x=~myNum or printf("%x", ~myNum), I suppose. And that something has a destination. If you want the result to be 16bits, you need to say it. uint16_t y=~myNum and printf("%hx", ~myNum) both do what you wanted. So no need for a cast to 16bits: start by not (implicitly) casting to 32 bits. So, said otherwise, show us the rest of the code: it is what matters.

@teapot418 Same thing just obfuscated. That expression too will lead to implicit promotion. On top of that it is a portability bug: on a 16 bit system you will get promotion to unsigned int because the type of 0xffff is then unsigned. But on a 32 bit system you will get promotion to int. Meaning that code like if(myNum ^ 0xffff > 0) is a severe but subtle portability bug. Best practice is to always add u suffix to hex constants, to avoid bugs like that.

@beyarkay, If the goal is clearly "want a neat 16-bit inversion?" ---> myNum ^ 0xFFFFu.

Short story: just cast back to the intended type, (uint16_t)~myNum

Long story: The problem is indeed that due to implicit promotion, almost all C operators that started on a small integer type such as char/short etc end up using int type instead. This is particularly troublesome in case you have a uint16_t on a 32 bit machine and apply ~, because the operand will get promoted to type int, the result will be of type int and therefore a negative value in this case.
General best practices with ~ is to always cast the result back to the intended type, in this case (uint16_t)~myNum. Conversion to unsigned is well-defined as per taking the mathematical value modulo 2^n, where n is the number of bits in the unsigned type. Or if you will, simply discard the upper bytes of the int, leaving us with 0x0000.
Also, even though there are implicit promotions present, the compiler is smart enough to tell that in case of (uint16_t)~myNum there are no unintended side-effects such as change of sign. So it could optimize this expression to get carried out of 16 bit types in the machine code, if that leads to faster execution (certainly the case on 8/16 bit CPUs). Whereas something like if(~myNum > 0) can't get carried out on 16 bits, because the implicit conversion to int caused a change of signedness and gave a negative value.
Best practice is to never writing code containing or relying on implicit promotion, or pretending that it isn't there. For example myNum = ~myNum; works too but this code could either mean two things: either the programmer thought of implicit promotion but realized it doesn't matter in this specific case. Or the programmer did not think of implicit promotion and just got the code right by luck. Whereas best practice myNum = (uint16_t)~myNum; means that the programmer did definitely consider it and in addition this will silence signed to unsigned implicit conversion warnings from the compiler/static analyzer.
